# How can I get this external drive to work on this machine?

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

- The device is an HGST Touro S (HTOSPA10001BHB)
- The machine is a (new) Asus T100 Chi running Win10 Home x64
- The error I get is a notification that says "USB device not recognized / The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.", and inside Device Manager is "Device Descriptor Request Failed"

The device is connected to the machine via OTG multi-cable.  The drive spins up and the light comes on as though nothing were wrong.  Other devices work fine through this same setup, and the device works fine on other machines.

Things I have tried, with no change in system behavior:

- Connect charger to the cable for extra power
- Update drivers
- (Re)Install Intel chipset driver package from ASUS support site
- Delete all USB devices in Device Manager (including hidden ones) and reboot so they reinstall
- Run the windows troubleshooter (which says it made some changes and prompts me to reboot)

Connecting through the other USB port (which is a [USB 3 micro-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Connector_USB_3_IMGP6033_wp.jpg) port, connected to a powered hub, connected to the device; I don't have a cable to go direct USB 3 micro-B to USB 3 micro-B) gives a different Device Manager error ("Port Reset Failed"), but still no dice.

Running MS's [USB Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17614/automatically-diagnose-and-fix-windows-usb-problems) tells me that "The USB Controller is in a failed state or is not currently installed.  The USB Controller must be installed or in a working state for this troubleshooter to run".  Interestingly, this does not change even if all the USB devices are freshly removed and auto-reinstalled with absolutely no USB devices connected.

**What am I missing here?  How can I get this to work properly?**

EDIT:  also tried booting from a live-linux Ubuntu medium.  Drive was also not recognized there, so seems like a hardware/firmware issue?

Comment: Does the drive work on a different computer?

Comment: Yes, works perfectly on at least three other machines (two desktops and a laptop, all running Win7).